# UITableViewCell accessory not positioned correctly after rotating UITableView on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have an iPhone app that I've converted to a **universal app**.

The app works fine in all orientation on the iPhone. However on iPad when I rotate a table view, the UITableViewCell accessory is not repositioned correctly (see images below). I'm using a standard UITableViewCell of type UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle. The rest of view is drawn correctly and uses all the iPad real estate. The XIB files are the same for the iPad and iPhone, except for the MainWindow.xib.

After scrolling down and backup, the accessory are redrawn at the correct position.

Does anyone know what could be causing that issue?

**EDIT:** If I remove the index list on the right, the problem disappears!

**Portrait orientation:**

[image]

**And when I rotate to landscape:**

[image]

**After scrolling down 2 cells and up again, the cell is refreshed and the accessory drawn at the correct position:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very well could be a bug and I'd recommend you file a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/

But for what it's worth, I don't think you should use a disclosure indicator along with an index -- none of the Apple apps feature this pattern. I was doing this myself until I noticed how Apple avoided it.

Comment: I haven't found a solution so far (besides calling reloadData in didRotateFromOrientation) so I filed a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the problem was I wasn't calling the base implementation of LayoutSubviews, s described here:

[UITableViewCell accessory chevron not right-aligning in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018532/uitableviewcell-accessory-chevron-not-right-aligning-in-ios7#answer-19069265)