# UITableViewCell accessory chevron not right-aligning in iOS7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I am attempting to upgrade a client to iOS7 but am having trouble with the accessoryType. As you can see here, when I launch in standard portrait mode it looks fine (the green background is something I applied to demonstrate how the UIViews are resizing):

[image]

As you can see the chevron is properly right-aligned. Now, if I rotate the device:

[image]

The chevron does not properly align itself at the right-edge of the screen. I tried applying an autoresizing mask to the accessory view, and about 10 other things, to no avail.

When I launch in iPad mode the chevron does not right align either in portrait or landscape mode.

I am setting this chevron by doing the following in the constructor of a custom UITableViewCell:

```
self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator
```

Note that scrolling the cells completely off the screen, then letting them fall back on-screen, causes the chevron to draw correctly right-aligned.

Can anyone suggest how to right-align chevrons properly in iOS7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out -- it's because I stupidly forgot to include a call to [super layoutSubviews] in my override of

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
```

Problem solved!